# How to linearize this bernoulii ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a Bernoulli ODE problem:

$$y'-xy=xy^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

To solve it I will linearize the ODE.

Let $z=y^{1-\frac{3}{2}}=y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ then $y=z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $y'=\frac{1}{2} z^{-\frac{1}{2}} z'$. Substitute in the ODE we have
\begin{align}
   & \frac{1}{2} z^{-\frac{1}{2}} z' - x z^{\frac{1}{2}} =x \left( z^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) ^{\frac{3}{2}}\nonumber\\
   \iff & \frac{1}{2} z' - x z =x  z^{\frac{3}{8}} \nonumber\\
   \iff &  z' - 2 x z =2x  z^{\frac{3}{8}}.\label{p1ba}
  \end{align}

But in the last ODE I can't get the linear ODE. What should be letting $z(x)$ such that the ODE can linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli's ODE is the form $y'+py=fy^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in \mathbf{R}$ and can be solved via substitution $u=y^{1-\alpha}$. In this case, we have the ODE $y'-xy=xy^{3/2}$ that is Bernoulli with $\alpha=3/2$, then $u=y^{1-3/2}=y^{-1/2}$ or $y=u^{-2}$. The chain rule give
$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}u}\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}=-2u^{-3}\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}.$$
Re-writing the ODE we have
$$ -2u^{-3}\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}-xu^{-2}=xu^{-3}$$
$$\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}+\frac{x}{2}u=-\frac{x}{2}$$
That is separable, with solution $u=ce^{-x^{2}/4}-1$ for some constant $c\in \mathbf{R}$. Hence the solution is follows since $y=u^{-2}$ so $y(x)=(ce^{-x^{2}/4}-1)^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch variables, you have
$$\frac 1 {x'}-x \,y=x\, y^{\frac 32}\quad \implies \frac {x'}x=\frac 1{y(1+\sqrt y)}$$
$$\log(x)+c=\int \frac {dy}{y(1+\sqrt y)}$$ Now, $y=z^2$ makes the integral simple.

When done, inverse to get $y$.